# R: Updating one table based on another

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

I have two dataframes, let's call them **A** and **B**. The dataframe **A** contains 5000 rows of information about the population in different regions of the UK. Something like that:

```
rowname      geographyID       age_bucket        income       population   
     1        E0100056            0-18            6000           567
     2        E0100056            19-64           28000          2437
     3        E0100056            65+             26000          789
     4        E0100082            0-18            6400           481
     .           .                  .               .             .
```

So there are 789 people aged 65+ in location E0100056 and their average annual income is £26000. geographyID an age_bucket are stored as characters, while income and population is numeric.

A subset of these locations now have new population estimates, and this is information is stored in dataframe **B**:

```
rowname      geographyID       age_bucket          population   
     1        E0100056            0-18               489
     2        E0100056            19-64              2743
     3        E0100056            65+                882
     .           .                  .               .
```

Only the geographyID-age_bucket combinations with changed data are stored in **B**, so it only has 80 rows.

What I need to do is to update the population numbers in **A** with the new numbers from **B**. For this I have tried creating a  "geographyID:age_bucket" index in both data frames, and use this to find the right information in **B** while mutating **A**:

```
 A$index <- with(A, paste(geographyID, age_bucket, sep=":"))
 B$index <- with(B, paste(geographyID, age_bucket, sep=":"))

 indicies_to_update <- B %>% pull("index")

  A <- A %>%
    mutate(
      population = ifelse(index %in% indicies_to_update, B[which(grepl(index, B$index)),which(colnames(B) == "population")] , population)
    )
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as the grepl() function throws an error (I think this is related to mutate passing the index as a vector). I am a complete beginner to R and fairly clueless about how to solve this. **Help is very welcome - thank you in advance!**

---

PS: as a further complication is that the **A** table contains some incorrect repeats of geographyID:age_bucket combinations (it shouldn't, but for reasons outside the scope of this post I cannot adjust this now). Hence, I am looking for a solution that would update all relevant rows.

Comment: Have you used  left or right join ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
A %>%
  left_join(
    B %>% rename(pop_b = population) %>% select(-rowname),
    by = c("geograhyID", "age_bucket")
  ) %>%
  mutate(population = coalesce(pop_b, population)) %>%
  select(-pop_b)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked when I removed the "select(-rowname)" (or "select(rownames)" - I tried both) bit. Is there a separate package I need to be able to reference the rownames column?

Comment: Well, the example data you show in your question looks like it has a first column named `rowname`. `select(-rowname)` removes that column, because we don't want to join on it. If it doesn't exist, then you don't have to worry about it. All I have to go on is what I see in your question.